# Не понимаю работу одного цикла

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не понимаю, как в этой программе написать "систему подсказок" (я хочу выводить первые 3 буквы загаданного слова, если пользователь ввёл "не знаю"). Ниже вы можете увидеть попытки написания цикла.

```
# Word Jumble
#
# The computer picks a random word and then "jumbles" it
# The player has to guess the original word

import random

# create a sequence of words to choose from
WORDS = ("торт", "автомобиль", "ананас", "берёза", "окунь", "революция")
# pick one word randomly from the sequence
word = random.choice(WORDS)
# create a variable to use later to see if the guess is correct
correct = word

# create a jumbled version of the word
jumble = ""
while word:
    position = random.randrange(len(word))
    jumble += word[position]
    word = word[:position] + word[(position + 1):]
    while jumble == word:
        position = random.randrange(len(word))
        jumble += word[position]
        word = word[:position] + word[(position + 1):]


# start the game
print(
    """
            Добро пожаловать в игру "Анаграммы"

        Расставьте буквы так, чтобы составить слово.
           На каждое слово Вам даётся 5 попыток
    Вы можете напечатать "не знаю", чтобы получить подсказку.
                 Подсказка стоит 1 балл.
"""
)
print("Ваша анаграмма", jumble)

guess = input("\nВаш ответ: ")

attempt = 1
points = 5
helps = word[0] + word[1] + word[2]

while guess != correct and guess != "":
    print("Неверно.")
    guess = input("\nВаш ответ: ")
    attempt += 1
    points -= 1
    if attempt < 5:
        print("Вы сделали", attempt, "попытки.")
    if attempt == 5:
        print("Вы сделали", attempt, "попыток.")
    if attempt >= 5:
        print("Извините, Вы не смогли угадать слово")
        break
    if guess == "не знаю":
        print("Подсказка: ", helps)
        points -= 1

if points < 0:
    points = 0

if guess == correct:
    print("Верно! Вы угадали слово с", attempt,
          "попытки и получили", points, "балл(а/ов)!\n")

print("Спасибо за игру.")

input("\n\nНажмите Enter чтобы выйти.")
```

Comment: А что не так? Не выводит подсказку? Или подсказка неправильно показывается? Пробовали запускать поставив везде print, отслеживая что не так пошло?

Comment: Просто пишет, что игрок неверно угадал, если ввести "не знаю"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В цикле `while word:` в строке `word = word[:position] + word[(position + 1):]` слово постепенно исчезает, соответственно в строке `help = word[0] +...` питону нечего вызывать по индексам - слова просто нет. Введите другую переменную в этот цикл, чтобы `word` не опустошалась. К примеру:

```
len_word = word
while len_word:
    position = random.randrange(len(len_word))
    jumble += len_word[position]
    len_word = len_word[:position] + len_word[(position + 1):]
    while jumble == len_word:
        position = random.randrange(len(len_word))
        jumble += len_word[position]
        len_word = len_word[:position] + len_word[(position + 1):]
```

Comment: извините, не особо понял, какую "другую" переменную тут нужно ввести?

Comment: @IlyaSidorchuk переменную, равную word, и все упоминания word в цикле заменить на её имя. всё заработало, сейчас дополню ответ

Comment: @IlyaSidorchuk ещё, кстати, нужно подкорректировать цикл, проверяющий правильность ввода - он выводит "Неверно" в любом случае, даже при вводе "не знаю"

Comment: Вот, в этом у меня тоже проблема, как сделать, чтобы при вводе "не знаю" она не писала "неверно"?

Comment: https://imgur.com/PKzxtmq -  я вот Ваш код вставил, исправил в коде все word на len_word

Comment: @IlyaSidorchuk выводить это только если ввод не равен "не знаю", то есть if gues != "не знаю": print("Неверно.")

Comment: @IlyaSidorchuk в переменной helps заменять word не нужно. отметьте ответ решением, если он вам помог.

Comment: https://imgur.com/O9ENHxB вот теперь это почему-то :(

Comment: если вас не устраивает засчитывание это как за попытку: перенесите её тоже под этот if.

Comment: А под какой if именно нужно перенести это?

Comment: @IlyaSidorchuk не увлекайтесь вопросами. если вы не хотите засчитывать попытку при слове не знаю, значит необходимо её переносить под сравнение ввода и слова "не знаю", то есть if gues != "не знаю":